# Не могу из FacesContext достать данные из JSF

Tags: javascript, java, отладка, jsf, primefaces

Уважаемые веб-программисты надеюсь вы меня направите на путь истины.
Смысл кода в том, чтобы пользователь тыкал на определенную область plot(график) и ему выводилась точечка на графике зеленая или красная, в зависимости оттого попал ли он в заданную область или нет(валидацию пройзводит сервер).
JSF код добавления скрипта под названием addClick

```
 <!-- Метод js для вызова метода на бине (ex. rc([{name: 'x', value: x}, {name: 'y', value: y}]))-->
<h:form>
<o:commandScript id="addClick"
                 name="addClick"
                 update="msgs, hitTable"
                 action="#{hitProcessor.serviceClick}"/>
</h:form>
```

Js код вызова метода addClick  и передача ему соответствующих x,y,r(радиус области)

```
clickPointEvent = (event) => {
let coordinates = getCoords(event);
let promise = addClick([{name: 'x', value: coordinates.x}, {name: 'y', value: coordinates.y}, {name: 'r', value: coordinates.r}]);
promise.then(function (responseData) {
    let hitResult = responseData.jqXHR.data.hitResult;
    console.log("Request successful, returned hit result is", hitResult);
    if (hitResult !== undefined) {
        addPoint(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, coordinates.r, hitResult);
        drawPoint(coordinates.x, coordinates.y, coordinates.r, hitResult);
    }
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error("Request failed", error);
});}
}
```

Js код получения координат по тыку на область

```
getCoords = (event) => {
let coordinates = {};
const rect = document.getElementById('plot').getBoundingClientRect();
coordinates.x = convertToCoordinatesX(event.clientX - rect.left);
coordinates.y = convertToCoordinatesY(event.clientY - rect.top);
coordinates.r = document.getElementById("form:R_value").value;
return coordinates;}
```

Код обработки данных x,y,r на сервере и отправка ответа попал/не попал

```
public void serviceClick() {
    log.info("Click detected!");
    Map<String,String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    System.out.println(params);
    int xCoordinate =Integer.valueOf(params.get("x"));
    int yCoordinate =Integer.valueOf(params.get("y"));
    System.out.println(xCoordinate);
    System.out.println(yCoordinate);
    Hit newClick = new Hit();
    newClick.setX(Double.valueOf(xCoordinate));
    newClick.setY(Double.valueOf(yCoordinate));
    newClick.setR(newHit.getR());
    serviceManager.serviceWithoutValidation(newClick);
    saveHit(newClick);
    PrimeFaces.current().ajax().addCallbackParam("hitResult", newClick.getResult());
}
```

При попытке дебага я начал выводил, что лежит в Map FacesContext - понял,что моих нужных данных там нет, но в js,когда я передаю в параметрах команды addClick все данные верны...
Что лежит в FacesContext

```
17:27:28,651 INFO  [stdout] (default task-1) {0=[object Object], 1=[object Object], 2=[object Object], ice.window=r4kzigvzll, javax.faces.behavior.event=action, ice.view=v8fbsbj2:0, javax.faces.ViewState=5123476603220133440:-590582843730420784, javax.faces.source=j_idt19:addClick, j_idt19=j_idt19, javax.faces.partial.ajax=true, javax.faces.partial.execute=j_idt19:addClick, javax.faces.ClientWindow=r4kzigvzll}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, что до конца понял суть, но всё же попробую предположить. Как я понял, проблема в том, что некие данные не передаются с клиента (браузер) на сервер. В *o:commandScript* указан атрибут *update* - это то, что должно быть обновлено **по завершению** запроса к серверу (*action*). Но нет атрибута *process* - это то, что должно быть передано на сервер **до обращения** к *action*. Т.е., на сервер не передаётся никаких данных.
Если результат выполнения JavaScript-а в браузере надо сделать доступным на сервере, можно создать скрытый HTML элемент(-ы) (обычно - input), заполнить его(их) значениями, которые требуется передать на сервер, и указать его(их) id в атрибуте *process* у *commandScript*-а

Comment: А как тогда передать данные из JavaScript-а в эти скрытые  input? Вот у меня есть переменная в JS  coordinate- она хранит в себе x y r,  а как мне coordinate.x  и coordinate.y  запихнуть в input  в JSF?